# How to pull most current date from two fields

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2012-express

I have a table that contains two Due Date fields.  Sometimes they both can match, sometimes one of them is blank, sometimes one of them is greater than the other.  I need how I can pull the most current Due Date into just one field from both fields.  The fields are PBDUE and XDCURDT and they are both datetime in the table.

Comment: Do you want a single value in the output, or do you want the most recent date from *each row* in the output? Showing sample data and desired results (as I did in my answer) is much more useful in describing the scenario than a word problem.

Comment: Sorry, I want just a single value in the output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming both columns are dates (date/datetime/etc.) and you mean `NULL` when you say *blank*:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN PBDUE >= XDCURDT THEN PBDUE ELSE XDCURDT END DUEDT
FROM (
    SELECT MAX(PBDUE) PBDUE, MAX(XDCURDT) XDCURDT FROM someTable
) t
```

The inner query computes the maximum (most recent) value of each column and the outer one returns the greatest (or `PBDUE` if both are equal).

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @x TABLE(ID INT,PBDUE DATE, XDCURDT DATE);

INSERT @x VALUES
(1,'2013-01-01','2012-01-01'), -- PBDUE greater
(2,'2010-01-01','2011-01-01'), -- XDCURDT greater
(3,NULL,'2009-01-01'), -- PBDUE "blank"
(4,'2008-01-01',NULL); -- XDCURDT "blank"

-- if you want one max date per row:

SELECT ID, MostCurrentDate = CASE
  WHEN PBDUE >= COALESCE(XDCURDT, '1900-01-01') THEN PBDUE
  WHEN XDCURDT >= COALESCE(PBDUE, '1900-01-01') THEN XDCURDT
  -- might want an ELSE if you don't want NULL
  -- when both values are NULL
  END
FROM @x
ORDER BY ID;

-- if you want one max date for the whole table:

SELECT MostCurrentDate = MAX(d) FROM (SELECT CASE
  WHEN PBDUE >= COALESCE(XDCURDT, '1900-01-01') THEN PBDUE
  WHEN XDCURDT >= COALESCE(PBDUE, '1900-01-01') THEN XDCURDT
  END
FROM @x) AS c(d);
```

Results:

```
ID   MostCurrentDate
--   ---------------
1    2013-01-01
2    2011-01-01
3    2009-01-01
4    2008-01-01

MostCurrentDate
---------------
2013-01-01
```